# Extract dependentLocality from CLPlacemark item

Tags: ios, swift, geocoding, cllocationmanager

I am trying to extract the dependentLocality information that is returned in a CLPlacemark object. The data (anonymized) looks like

```
{
            "cache_control" = CACHEABLE;
            "start_index" = 0;
            status = "STATUS_SUCCESS";
            ttl = 15768000;
            type = "COMPONENT_TYPE_ADDRESS";
            value =                 (
                                    {
                    address =                         {
                        "known_accuracy" = POINT;
                        "localized_address" =                             (
                                                            {
                                address =                                     {
                                    formattedAddressLine =                                         (
                                        "111 Some St",
                                        "Brooklyn, NY  11111-1111",
                                        "United States"
                                    );
                                    structuredAddress =                                         {
                                        administrativeArea = "New York";
                                        administrativeAreaCode = NY;
                                        areaOfInterest =                                             (
                                            "Long Island"
                                        );
                                        country = "United States";
                                        countryCode = US;
                                        dependentLocality =                                             (
                                            "Bedford Stuyvesant",
                                            Brooklyn
                                        );
                                        fullThoroughfare = "111 Some St";
                                        geoId =                                             (
                                        );
                                        locality = "New York";
                                        postCode = 11206;
                                        postCodeExtension = 1111;
                                        postCodeFull = "11111-1111";
                                        subAdministrativeArea = Kings;
                                        subLocality = Brooklyn;
                                        subThoroughfare = 111;
                                        thoroughfare = "Some St";
                                    };
                                };
                                locale = "en_US";
                            }
                        );
                    };
                }
            );
            "values_available" = 1;
            version = 7;
            "version_domain" =                 (
                apple,
                revgeo,
                US
            );
        },
```

I can't access the contents (other than through Apple's structuredAddress property, which doesn't contain what I want). I want to extract "Bedford Stuyvesant", Brooklyn" from what's above, for instance. Have tried numerous ways around this, but eg. casting the placemark to an NSDictionary fails. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I looked into this further and it is impossible to cast CLPlacemark objects to NSDictionary (or anything else, apparently), so this seems to be impossible with the standard CoreLocation methods.

Comment: The `subLocality` property for New York City locations is not getting assigned properly. Take a look at some other parts of the country and you'll see neighborhood names show up regularly.  For example in San Francisco, Nob Hill, Russian Hill, Cow Hollow all show up in the `subLocality` property. I've been able to extract the `dependentLocality` but it's not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do some string processing to extract dependentLocality from your placemark.description. But why don't you just use placemark.subLocality property?

```
NSString *geoMapItem = placemark.description;
NSRange start = [geoMapItem rangeOfString:@"dependentLocality"];
NSRange end = [geoMapItem rangeOfString:@")" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(start.location, 1000)];
NSString *dataString = [geoMapItem substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start.location, end.location - start.location + end.length)];
dataString = [dataString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
dataString = [dataString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@""];
dataString = [dataString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];

start = [dataString rangeOfString:@"("];
end = [dataString rangeOfString:@")"];
NSString *arrayString = [dataString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start.location + 1, end.location - start.location - 1)];

NSArray *array = [arrayString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Comment: Because 1: no string, array or dictionary methods work on a CLPlacemark, and 2: placemark.subLocality does not return the desired result (eg. returns "Brooklyn" instead of dependentLocality's "Crown Heights, Brooklyn").

Comment: I added some string processing code to extract dependentLocality :-)